# pubsub publish to node success, retrieve from node fail

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

Below showed i suggest published to node call "ghost2"

```
iq id="kB8dk-0" to="computer/2c10ee6b" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>admin@computer/Smack</jid></bind></iq>
<iq id="kB8dk-1" to="admin@computer/Smack" type="result"></iq>
<iq id="kB8dk-2" to="admin@computer/Smack" type="result"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="test" name="test" subscription="none"></item><item jid="test@computer" subscription="from"></item></query></iq>
<message id="admin@computer__admin@computer__ChWrY" to="admin@computer" from="admin@computer"><event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'><items node='null'><item id='ghost2'/></items></event></message>
<iq id="kB8dk-4" to="admin@computer/Smack" from="computer" type="result"></iq>
<iq id="kB8dk-5" to="admin@computer/Smack" from="computer" type="result"></iq>
<message id="ghost2__admin@computer__DGaLS" to="admin@computer" from="admin@computer"><event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'><items node='ghost2'><item id='testid2'><book xmlns="pubsub:test:book"><title>book x</title></book></item></items></event></message>
```

but when i try to subsript and retrieve from the same node , i get error 404

```
<iq id="zpWDI-0" to="computer/b7fe68a8" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>test@computer/Smack</jid></bind></iq>
<iq id="zpWDI-1" to="test@computer/Smack" type="result"></iq>
<iq id="zpWDI-2" to="test@computer/Smack" type="result"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="admin@computer" name="test" subscription="to"><group>Friends</group></item><item jid="test" name="test" subscription="none"></item></query></iq>
<presence id="kB8dk-3" to="test@computer/Smack" from="admin@computer/Smack"></presence>
<message id="admin@computer__test@computer__tAVfB" to="test@computer/Smack" from="admin@computer"><event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'><items node='TestNode2323'><item id='2Ke42PVQ77iSCP0'><book xmlns="pubsub:test:book"><title>book x</title></book></item></items></event><x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" stamp="20091013T14:16:32"></x><addresses xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/address"><address type="replyto" jid="admin@computer/god"/></addresses></message>
<iq id="zpWDI-4" to="test@computer/Smack" from="computer" type="error"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info" node="ghost2"></query><error code="404" type="CANCEL"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've received the published item:

```
<book xmlns="pubsub:test:book"><title>book x</title></book>
```

You've received the 404 error from "computer" (your xmpp server) for this query:

```
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info" node="ghost2"></query>
```

Which hast to do with service discovery. Is it possible that you've removed some messages from the complete conversation?

Edit:

Could you try to replace:

```
PubSubManager manager = new PubSubManager(connection, "computer");
```

with this

```
String pubSubAddress = "pubsub." + connection.getServiceName();
PubSubManager manager = new PubSubManager(connection, pubSubAddress);
```

Comment: I thought you might have removed some messages for readability, e.g. as you meant they are unrelated. But as mentioned in a comment to your last question: What library are you using for pubsub? I'm using pubsub as well, but never had to worry about raw messages.

Comment: im using smackx pubsub  . you?

Comment: also, from the response, the "book x " is from node "TestNode2323" .. can you comment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can be used as a reference for you：

```
public void login(String Ip,String username,String passwaord)
     {
         try 
         {
            connConfig = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(Ip, 5222);
            connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
            connection.connect();  
            connection.login(username, passwaord);
            pubSubAddress = "pubsub."+ connection.getServiceName();
            manager = new PubSubManager(connection,pubSubAddress);
            Log.i("MyError","connection success");  
         }
         catch (XMPPException e) 
         {
             Log.i("MyError","connection failed");      
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }
```

In addition, you may refer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808549/item-not-found404-when-trying-to-get-a-node-using-smackx-pubsub) which is relevant to yours.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to this example:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.ItemPublishEvent;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.Node;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PayloadItem;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.listener.ItemEventListener;
public class XmppPubsub_Reciever {
    private static XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection("think");
    private static String USRE_NAME = "user";
    private static String PASSWORD = "1";
    static {
        try {
            connection.connect();
            connection.login(USRE_NAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String nodeId = "test";
        PubSubManager manager = new PubSubManager(connection);
        Node eventNode = manager.getNode(nodeId);
        eventNode.addItemEventListener(new ItemEventListener<PayloadItem>() {
            public void handlePublishedItems(ItemPublishEvent evt) {
                for (Object obj : evt.getItems()) {
                    PayloadItem item = (PayloadItem) obj;
                    System.out.println("--:Payload=" + item.getPayload().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        eventNode.subscribe(connection.getUser());
        while(true);
    }
}
```