# item-not-found(404) when trying to get a node using Smackx pubsub

Tags: java, coldfusion, xmpp, openfire, smack

I'm trying to use the latest Smackx trunk to get and then subscribe to a pubsub node. However, openfire just sends me a back an error: item not found (404).

I am instantiating the java objects from ColdFusion, so my code snippets might look funny but maybe someone will be able to tell me what I've forgotten.

Here's how I create the node:

```
    ftype = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.FormType");
    cform = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.ConfigureForm").init(ftype.submit);
    cform.setPersistentItems(true);
    cform.setDeliverPayloads(true);
    caccess = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.AccessModel");
    cform.setAccessModel(caccess.open);
    cpublish = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PublishModel");
    cform.setPublishModel(cpublish.open);
    cform.setMaxItems(99);

    manager = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager").init(XMPPConnection);

    myNode = manager.createNode("subber", cform);
```

And here's how I am trying to get to it (in a different section of code):

```
    manager = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager").init(XMPPConnection);
    myNode = manager.getNode("subber");
```

Immediately upon **creating** the node I seem to be able to publish to it like so:

```
    payload = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.SimplePayload").init("book","pubsub:test:book","<book xmlns='pubsub:test:book'><title>Lord of the Rings</title></book>");
    item = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.Item").init(payload);
    myNode.publish(item);
```

However, it is the getNode() call that is causing my code to error.

I have verified that the nodes are being created by checking the DB used by my openfire server. I can see them in there, properly attributed as leaf nodes, etc.

Any advice?
Anyone else out there doing anything with XMPP and ColdFusion?
I have had great success sending and receiving messages with CF and Smack just haven't had the pubsub working yet :)

Thanks!

Comment: update: it looks like for some reason the nodes are being created with the user's JID as the serviceID in the DB. When I create a node (using Strophe.js) it sets the serviceID as pubsub and this seems to yield a working node. How do I set Smack to give "pubsub" as the service id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered:

There is a second method on the PubSubManager class that accepts two arguments, a connection and a **to** parameter. Apparently Openfire requires this **to** parameter and after some experimenting i discovered that it works using pubsub.your.xmpp.address

```
manager = createObject("java", "org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager").init(XMPPConnection,"pubsub.127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can be used as a reference for you：

```
 public void login(String Ip,String username,String passwaord)
     {
         try 
         {
            connConfig = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(Ip, 5222);
            connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
            connection.connect();  
            connection.login(username, passwaord);
            pubSubAddress = "pubsub."+ connection.getServiceName();
            manager = new PubSubManager(connection,pubSubAddress);
            Log.i("MyError","connection success");  
         }
         catch (XMPPException e) 
         {
             Log.i("MyError","connection failed");      
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A normalized example are showed as following:

Publish node:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.LeafNode;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PayloadItem;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.SimplePayload;

public class XmppPubsub_Publisher {
    private static XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection("think");
    private static String USRE_NAME = "test1";
    private static String PASSWORD = "1";
    static{
        try {
            connection.connect();
            connection.login(USRE_NAME,PASSWORD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        try{
            PubSubManager manager = new PubSubManager(connection);
            String nodeId = "test2";
            LeafNode myNode = null;
            try {
                myNode = manager.getNode(nodeId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(myNode == null){
                myNode = manager.createNode(nodeId);
            }
            String msg = "fsadfasdfsadfasdfd---";
            SimplePayload payload = new SimplePayload("message","pubsub:test:message", "<message xmlns='pubsub:test:message'><body>"+msg+"</body></message>");
            PayloadItem<SimplePayload> item = new PayloadItem<SimplePayload>("5", payload);
            myNode.publish(item);
            System.out.println("-----publish-----------");
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {E.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Retrieve node:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.ItemPublishEvent;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.Node;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PayloadItem;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.listener.ItemEventListener;

public class XmppPubsub_Reciever {
    private static XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection("think");
    private static String USRE_NAME = "test1";
    private static String PASSWORD = "1";
    static {
        try {
            connection.connect();
            connection.login(USRE_NAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String nodeId = "test2";
        PubSubManager manager = new PubSubManager(connection);
        Node eventNode = manager.getNode(nodeId);
        eventNode.addItemEventListener(new ItemEventListener<PayloadItem>() {
            public void handlePublishedItems(ItemPublishEvent evt) {
                for (Object obj : evt.getItems()) {
                    PayloadItem item = (PayloadItem) obj;
                    System.out.println("--:Payload=" + item.getPayload().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        eventNode.subscribe(connection.getUser());
        while(true);
    }
}
```